# My extractMin function for a binary search tree isn't working properly

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, min

I wrote the main extractMin function and the helper function that actually does the extracting. However, if I call the function twice in main it returns the same value.

```
    double findMin(node * p)
    {
        if(p == NULL)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = p;
            while(temp->left != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->left;
            }
            return temp->data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, your ***find*** function doesn't remove anything. It doesn't even *search* for anything, besides the last node in (practically) a linked list.

Comment: what is the question? If you need help fixing a bug you should provide a [mcve] and expected & actual output

Comment: Isn't the minimum node in a BST the leftmost node?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, well, given it is a BST, it would be the minimal node. So you can stretch it and call it `findMin`. But it certainly doesn't remove anything.

Comment: Only if you keep on reorder it after you actually remove leaves. And you don't remove any leaves, much less reorder the tree.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since it is a binary *search* tree it should be ordered by definition. But then, I don't know what "call the function back to back" means.

Comment: @JoshGarza Could you edit your question to contain more information on how you are calling the function? "Call the function back to back" does not ring a bell, at least for me. A working example with the tree would greatly improve the chances for an answer.

Comment: Your problem is in the extract function (which you didn't post).